# Any way to monitor API requests to a Google Analytics profile?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My application's requests to a specific GA profile continue to be denied with a '403 dailyLimitExceeded' error, even in the early morning after the quota is reset at 12am PT.

The account holder is not aware of any other authorized access that would be making requests against that quota.

Is there a way to monitor requests for a profile to understand what is using up the quota, similar to API Console monitoring for projects? Are there things that use this quota that may not be obvious?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The limit is per Google project, is it possible anyone else is using it?  Perhaps the real.time API may be tripping you over.

Comment: The error is specific to the profile  `profileId ga:149##### has exceeded the daily request limit`

Comment: Is your application being used by multiple users within the same organisation?  And does it use realTime reporting?